# Monitor license server for JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler, kubernetes-health-check, health-check

I would need to run EJ technologies license server for serving floating license for JProfiler. Furthermore, I need to **monitor the service** via monitoring solutions (i.e. prometheus), properly.

So question is, from an operational perspective, how to determine, if the license server is "healthy", means not only the process is running and the TCP socket is there, but the service does the job?

Comment: The first step for this answer is: How do you monitor if the service is working when  deployed on a normal server? Because this answer is the path to implementing on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no health check port for the license server. What you can do is to run

```
bin/admin -list
```

and check if the process exit code is 0. If the exit code is 1, the license server is not running or unresponsive.